# How to change Sleep settings dropdown value in windows 10 from CMD prompt?

Tags: node.js, command-prompt

change Sleep settings dropdown value in windows 10 from CMD prompt and should set value in power and sleep settings dropdown.

Comment: I don't see any reason for **node**.js tag.

Comment: actually i used node js for my full application with electron js that is why i mentioned node but if there any solution on any language is no problem.